# Siri Extension with Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data, siri, sirishortcuts, ios-targets

Currently, I am able to create a siri shortcut in my xcode app and it displays a view, but I want to make it dynamic to show records via my core data. However, I am not able to query my core data from my intent handler.

```
import UIKit
import Intents
import os.log

public class ViewMyMedIntentHandler: NSObject, ViewMyMedsIntentHandling {

    public func confirm(intent: ViewMyMedsIntent, completion: @escaping (ViewMyMedsIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        os_log("TK421: %{public}s", "\(#function)")
        completion(ViewMyMedsIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: nil))
    }
    
    public func handle(intent: ViewMyMedsIntent, completion: @escaping (ViewMyMedsIntentResponse) -> Void) {
            os_log("TK421: %{public}s", "\(#function)")
            
        let meds = Siri.shared.getData(forUserID: "296CAD6062")
        
        if meds.isEmpty {
            let response = ViewMyMedsIntentResponse(code: .failsuccess, userActivity: nil)
            completion(response)
        } else {
            let response = ViewMyMedsIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
            response.successMessage = meds
            completion(response)
        }
    }
}
```

and then here is the getData function which is querying the database

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Siri {
    static let shared = Siri() // Create a shared instance
        
        var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
        
        init() {
            persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PillNotify")
            persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }

    func getData(forUserID userID: String) -> [String] {
            let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
            
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MedicineData")
            fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
            fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["medicinename"]
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "seniorid = %@", userID)
            
            do {
                let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [[String: Any]]
                let meds = results?.compactMap { $0["medicinename"] as? String } ?? []
                return meds
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch values. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                return []
            }
        }
}
```

However, all that is being returned is an empty array and no meds are displaying. I'm not sure if it has to do with having the files in specific targets

Here is a screen shot of my result

[Here is a screen shot of my result when i say view my meds to siri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cwZq.png)

This is my code for creating the siri shortcut, just in case you would need it to answer the question.

```
import SwiftUI
import IntentsUI
import os.log
import Intents

struct MedsViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let activity: NSUserActivity?

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MedsViewControllerWrapper {
        return MedsViewControllerWrapper(activity: activity)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MedsViewControllerWrapper, context: Context) {
        // Update the view controller if needed
    }

    typealias UIViewControllerType = MedsViewControllerWrapper
}

class MedsViewControllerWrapper: UIViewController {
    private let container = UIView()
    private let button = UIButton()
    private let activity: NSUserActivity?

    init(activity: NSUserActivity?) {
        self.activity = activity
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpSubviews()
    }

    @objc func addSiriShortcutButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: ViewMyMedsIntent()) else {
            return
        }
        let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
        viewController.delegate = self
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func setUpSubviews() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(container)

        button.setTitle("Enable Read Meds Siri Shortcut", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addSiriShortcutButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)

        addConstraints()
    }

    private func addConstraints() {
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // Container constraints remain the same
            
            // Center the button horizontally
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerYAnchor),
            // Set the button width to be equal to the width of the view minus the horizontal margin (20)
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor, constant: -40),
            // Align the button's top to the bottom of the container with a spacing of 10
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
        ])

        // Set the button's corner radius to make it rounded
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 13.0
        // Clip to bounds to ensure the rounded corners are visible
        button.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}



extension MedsViewControllerWrapper: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButtonDelegate {
    func present(_ addVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        present(addVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func present(_ editVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        present(editVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


extension MedsViewControllerWrapper: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {
    func addVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, didFinishWith voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            os_log("Error adding voice shortcut: %@", log: OSLog.default, type: .error, error)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension MedsViewControllerWrapper: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {
    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController,
                                         didUpdate voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?,
                                         error: Error?) {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            os_log("Error adding voice shortcut: %@", log: OSLog.default, type: .error, error)
        }

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController,
                                         didDeleteVoiceShortcutWithIdentifier deletedVoiceShortcutIdentifier: UUID) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and here is my code for the UI view for the top part that says "Medications:"

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

public class MedsView: UIView {
    private let contentView = UIView()
    private let cardView = UIView()
    private let stackView = UIStackView()
    private let medView = UIView()
    private let medLabel = UILabel()
    
    var meds = ""
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        extractData(data: Siri.shared.getData(forUserID: "296CAD6062"))
        setUpSubViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemented")
    }
    
}

private extension MedsView {
    func setUpSubViews() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:  129/255, green: 159/255, blue: 247/255, alpha: 1)
        addSubview(contentView)
        
        cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        
        cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.12
        contentView.addSubview(cardView)
        
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 0
        cardView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        
        medLabel.text = "Medications: \n\n\(meds)"
        medLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        medLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // Allow multiple lines for the label
        medLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
        medLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:  69/255, green: 80/255, blue: 81/255, alpha: 1)
        medView.addSubview(medLabel)
        
        medLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            medLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medView.leadingAnchor),
            medLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medView.trailingAnchor),
            medLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            medView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
        ])
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(medView)
        
        addConstraints()
    }

    
    func addConstraints() {
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        medLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Add this line to disable autoresizing mask translation for the label

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),

            cardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            cardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),

            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            cardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView.topAnchor),
            cardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor),

            medLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medView.leadingAnchor),
            medLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            medView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: medLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
        ])
    }
    
    func extractData(data: [String])
    {
        var count = 0
        for i in data
        {
            if count == data.count - 1
            {
                meds += i
                count += 1
            }
            else
            {
                meds += i
                meds += "\n"
                count += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[it should be displaying these medicines instead of being blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF2nJ.png)

I tried creating a file that is both my main target app and the IntentKit framework target which has a func for querying the core database, however, my core database can only be in my main target app otherwise I get an error. But regardless, I try to get an id from UserDefaults keys and then query the medicine name and then display it.